# Change saturation of rendered object without changing the background Image

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, color

I´ve recently rendered a hand sanitizer on to a background image, and although it looks half ok, I noticed I had to reduce the saturation of the model to match the background image.

Unfortunately, when I go into render settings and change the saturation, it also affects my background image. Does anybody know how to apply saturation only to the model?

Look forward to your comments.

Many thanks,

Karl.
[image]

Comment: The image in the question is pre or post adjustment? Maybe you could just adjust the lights in the render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ID mask to do this.

Select the object you wish to color, go into object settings and change the pass index to 1.
[image]

Now go into the layer properties menu and enable "Object index" under passes.

[image]

Hit render. Now go into the compositor and add a viewer node so you can see what you are doing. You can use the "id mask" node as a mask for the object. Here I have setup a simple node network that will achieve what you want:

[image]